# Can't print on Brother DCP 1612W

Tags: printing, brother

I would really appreciate some help as I have spent several days trying to figure out what is going on.

I have recently bought new printer Brother DCP-1612W and would like to use. Ubuntu  14.04.2 LTS. CUPS finds the printer as wireless printer:

Description:    Brother DCP-1610W series
Location:
Driver: Brother DCP-1610W for CUPS (grayscale, 2-sided printing)
Connection: dnssd://Brother%20DCP-1610W%20series._pdl-datastream._tcp.local/
Defaults:   job-sheets=none, none media=na_letter_8.5x11in sides=one-sided

or as USB printer when the cable is connected:

Connection:     usb://Brother/DCP-1610W%20series?serial=E74238J5N865607

But I can't print. Nothing comes out. I have MAC notebook where installation went paint free and wireless printing works fine.

I will really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Download the drivers:

```
http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf101533/dcp1610wlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb
http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf101532/dcp1610wcupswrapper-3.0.1-1.i386.deb
```

Install the drivers:

Turn on the printer and connect the usb, network or parallel cable.

Go to the directory where the drivers are.

```
Run it:
sudo -i
dpkg -i --force-all dcp1610wlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb
dpkg  -i  --force-all dcp1610wcupswrapper-3.0.1-1.i386.deb
nano /etc/printcap
```

Edit the /etc/printcap file according to your connection.

For USB Connection:

Check if the parameter of `:lp` is `:lp=/dev/usb/lp0`

For Network Connection:

Replace `:lp` line to the following 2 lines:

```
:rm=(ip address of your printer)\
:rp=lp\
```

Restart the PC.

Comment: Thanks  lot. I purged the drivers and did it again from the scratch  as you explained. I don't know what I have done differently but it worked this time. May be the order of LPR and CUPS driver or restarting PC at the end ....it works fine now.

Comment: Hey. I've an opened question regarding something similar https://askubuntu.com/questions/814327/printer-brother-dcp-1610w-not-working-under-xubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1232244_814327

I'm trying to re-install using dpkg using your commands but I get the following error:

http://pastebin.com/76JEPJPm

Answer (score 0):

Under Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64
I did the installation as instructed on the Brother site. Everything went well at first glance, but after looking back at the terminal I noticed this:

> ```
> Aucune version du paquet ia32-libs n'est disponible, mais il existe dans la base
> de données. Cela signifie en général que le paquet est manquant, qu'il est devenu obsolète
> ou qu'il n'est disponible que sur une autre source
> Cependant les paquets suivants le remplacent :
>   lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
> ```

Sorry for the French version. Loosely translated it says: No version of the package ia32-libs available.
So, after installing the 3 packages before mentioned, the printer is working just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to print on a Brother DCP-1612W with my Ubuntu 18.04 using WLAN.

After setting up WLAN for the printer and connecting my printer and laptop with the corresponding WLAN, I used the `system-config-printer` tool. I started adding a new printer. The tool detected the printer letting it appear on the list and suggesting an `LPD/LPR` and a `AppSocket/JetDirect` connection. I chose the latter. The driver wizard pointed me to a `Brother DCP-1510 driver`. Although not quite my printer model, using that driver, I was able to use the wireless printer as far as I needed it. Done for me!

Hope to have helped.