# Printer Brother DCP 1610W not working under Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, printing, brother

I'm trying to print something on my desktop with Xubuntu 16.04 but I'm being unsuccessfull. The weird thing is that it works perfectly on my laptop (with the same version OS, same drivers, etc).

Here are the outputs of

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

before and after plugging my printer:

```
Aug 19 11:50:26 mypc kernel: [  124.382330] usblp 3-10.3:1.0: usblp1: USB Bidirectional printer dev 5 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04F9 pid 0x035B
Aug 19 11:50:50 mypc org.freedesktop.PackageKit[3064]: DEBUG:Checking for inactivity (30s)
Aug 19 11:51:20 mypc org.freedesktop.PackageKit[3064]: DEBUG:Checking for inactivity (60s)
Aug 19 11:51:36 mypc kernel: [  193.883546] usb 3-10.3: USB disconnect, device number 5
Aug 19 11:51:36 mypc kernel: [  193.883747] usblp1: removed
Aug 19 11:51:36 mypc udev-configure-printer[5268]: remove /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10/3-10.3
Aug 19 11:51:36 mypc udev-configure-printer[5268]: URI of detected printer: usb://Brother/DCP-1610W%20series?serial=E74230B5N526398, normalized: brother dcp 1610w series serial e74230b5n526398
Aug 19 11:51:36 mypc udev-configure-printer[5268]: URI of print queue: usb://Brother/DCP-1610W%20series?serial=E74230B5N526398, normalized: brother dcp 1610w series serial e74230b5n526398
Aug 19 11:51:36 mypc udev-configure-printer[5268]: Queue ipp://localhost/printers/Brother-DCP-1610W-series has matching device URI
Aug 19 11:51:36 mypc udev-configure-printer[5268]: Disabled printer ipp://localhost/printers/Brother-DCP-1610W-series as the corresponding device was unplugged or turned off
Aug 19 11:51:40 mypc colord-sane: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
Aug 19 11:51:43 mypc kernel: [  200.962335] usb 3-10.3: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Aug 19 11:51:43 mypc kernel: [  201.051201] usb 3-10.3: New USB device found, idVendor=04f9, idProduct=035b
Aug 19 11:51:43 mypc kernel: [  201.051204] usb 3-10.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=3
Aug 19 11:51:43 mypc kernel: [  201.051205] usb 3-10.3: SerialNumber: E74230B5N526398
Aug 19 11:51:43 mypc kernel: [  201.053024] usblp 3-10.3:1.0: usblp1: USB Bidirectional printer dev 6 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04F9 pid 0x035B
Aug 19 11:51:43 mypc systemd[1]: Starting Automatic USB/Bluetooth printer setup (-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb3-3\x2d10-3\x2d10.3)...
Aug 19 11:51:43 mypc udev-configure-printer[5285]: add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10/3-10.3
Aug 19 11:51:43 mypc udev-configure-printer[5285]: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10/3-10.3
Aug 19 11:51:43 mypc udev-configure-printer[5285]: MFG:Brother MDL:DCP-1610W series SERN:- serial:E74230B5N526398
Aug 19 11:51:43 mypc kernel: [  201.078847] audit_printk_skb: 63 callbacks suppressed
Aug 19 11:51:43 mypc kernel: [  201.078850] audit: type=1400 audit(1471603903.429:118): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/ippusbxd" name="/etc/ld.so.preload" pid=5299 comm="ippusbxd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Aug 19 11:51:47 mypc colord-sane: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
Aug 19 11:51:48 mypc kernel: [  206.136838] audit: type=1400 audit(1471603908.485:119): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/etc/ld.so.preload" pid=5309 comm="cups-exec" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Aug 19 11:51:48 mypc kernel: [  206.137116] audit: type=1400 audit(1471603908.485:120): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/etc/ld.so.preload" pid=5309 comm="cups-deviced" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Aug 19 11:51:48 mypc kernel: [  206.140017] audit: type=1400 audit(1471603908.489:121): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/etc/ld.so.preload" pid=5311 comm="ipp" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=7 ouid=0
Aug 19 11:51:48 mypc kernel: [  206.145184] audit: type=1400 audit(1471603908.493:122): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/etc/ld.so.preload" pid=5314 comm="serial" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Aug 19 11:51:48 mypc kernel: [  206.148449] audit: type=1400 audit(1471603908.497:123): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/etc/ld.so.preload" pid=5316 comm="ipps" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=7 ouid=0
Aug 19 11:51:48 mypc kernel: [  206.150067] audit: type=1400 audit(1471603908.497:124): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/etc/ld.so.preload" pid=5320 comm="usb" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Aug 19 11:51:48 mypc kernel: [  206.156124] usblp1: removed
Aug 19 11:51:48 mypc kernel: [  206.163011] usblp 3-10.3:1.0: usblp1: USB Bidirectional printer dev 6 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04F9 pid 0x035B
Aug 19 11:51:48 mypc hp[5313]: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
Aug 19 11:51:48 mypc python3: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
Aug 19 11:51:48 mypc udev-configure-printer[5285]: URI contains USB serial number
Aug 19 11:51:48 mypc udev-configure-printer[5285]: URI match: usb://Brother/DCP-1610W%20series?serial=E74230B5N526398
Aug 19 11:51:48 mypc udev-configure-printer[5285]: URI of detected printer: usb://Brother/DCP-1610W%20series?serial=E74230B5N526398, normalized: brother dcp 1610w series serial e74230b5n526398
Aug 19 11:51:48 mypc udev-configure-printer[5285]: URI of print queue: usb://Brother/DCP-1610W%20series?serial=E74230B5N526398, normalized: brother dcp 1610w series serial e74230b5n526398
Aug 19 11:51:48 mypc udev-configure-printer[5285]: Queue ipp://localhost/printers/Brother-DCP-1610W-series has matching device URI
Aug 19 11:51:48 mypc udev-configure-printer[5285]: Re-enabled printer ipp://localhost/printers/Brother-DCP-1610W-series
Aug 19 11:51:48 mypc systemd[1]: Started Automatic USB/Bluetooth printer setup (-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb3-3\x2d10-3\x2d10.3).
Aug 19 11:51:50 mypc org.freedesktop.PackageKit[3064]: DEBUG:Checking for inactivity (90s)
```

My printer is the Brother-DCP 1610w. I can scan perfectly fine with it, it's just the printing that's not working. Under "Printers", I see the printer there with the green check-mark, though after asking to print something, nothing happens. If I go to "Printers", I see the jobs as "completed".

Any idea what might be happening and I should I go about fixing this? I've obviously already restarted both the computer and the printer. I've also already installed these drivers: [Downloads - DCP-1610W | support.brother.com](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=as_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp1610w_eu_as&os=128)

EDIT:
Doing `sudo cat /etc/cups/printers.conf` while the printer is turned OFF gives me the following:

```
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v2.1.3
# Written by cupsd
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
<DefaultPrinter Brother-DCP-1610W-series>
UUID urn:uuid:3f49b902-e331-31f5-558a-cf8be931977d
Info Brother DCP-1610W series
Location mypc
MakeModel Brother DCP-1610W for CUPS
DeviceURI usb://Brother/DCP-1610W%20series?serial=E74230B5N526398
State Stopped
StateMessage Unplugged or turned off
StateTime 1471611395
ConfigTime 1471603824
Reason paused
Type 8392708
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy retry-job
</DefaultPrinter>
<Printer DCP1610W>
UUID urn:uuid:b62f3751-a91c-39b0-59ee-2fb82efd5755
Info DCP1610W
MakeModel Brother DCP-1610W for CUPS
DeviceURI usb://Brother/DCP-1610W%20series?serial=E74230B5N526398
State Stopped
StateMessage Unplugged or turned off
StateTime 1471611395
ConfigTime 1471606686
Reason paused
Type 8392708
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy retry-job
</Printer>
```

With the printer ON, I get:

```
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v2.1.3
# Written by cupsd
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
<DefaultPrinter Brother-DCP-1610W-series>
UUID urn:uuid:3f49b902-e331-31f5-558a-cf8be931977d
Info Brother DCP-1610W series
Location mypc
MakeModel Brother DCP-1610W for CUPS
DeviceURI usb://Brother/DCP-1610W%20series?serial=E74230B5N526398
State Idle
StateTime 1471702911
ConfigTime 1471603824
Type 8392708
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy retry-job
</DefaultPrinter>
<Printer DCP1610W>
UUID urn:uuid:b62f3751-a91c-39b0-59ee-2fb82efd5755
Info DCP1610W
MakeModel Brother DCP-1610W for CUPS
DeviceURI usb://Brother/DCP-1610W%20series?serial=E74230B5N526398
State Idle
StateTime 1471702911
ConfigTime 1471606686
Type 8392708
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy retry-job
</Printer>
```

Comment: Are you connected to it over the LAN or over USB?

Comment: Could please edit your post and paste the output of this command? `sudo cat /etc/cups/printers.conf`

Comment: @AndroidDev, I've it connected over USB.

Comment: @ThiagoRiderAugusto, I've added the output of your command to my post.

Answer (score 3):

Your 1610 printer is listed twice in `/etc/cups/printers.conf` with different UUID's each time.

In my configuration file the Brother printer is only listed once:

```
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v2.1.3
# Written by cupsd
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
<DefaultPrinter DCP7065DN>
UUID urn:uuidzf3a944e2-df3b-3462-73f0-bf2d45b99cdf
Info DCP7065DN
MakeModel Brother DCP7065DN for CUPS
DeviceURI usb://Brother/DCP-7065DN?serial=U62712M1N423077
State Idle
StateTime 1472268209
ConfigTime 1470519913
Type 8392724
Accepting Ves
Shared Ves
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy retry-job
</DefaultPrinter>
```

I would delete your second printer starting from `<Printer DCP1610W>` down to the last line of the file `</Printer>`.

Before editing `/etc/cups/printers.conf` you need to stop cupsd service with:

```
sudo systemctl stop cups
```

Then do your edit. After saving your configuration file restart cupsd service with:

```
sudo systemctl start cups
```

One caveat I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 not Xubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Take a look at the [source](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/98ae1772-30c6-4bfd-961d-274599aa61ff/view-source) for the latest revision of the post. Those indented lines (4 spaces) will allow you to format in code blocks. Alternatively, you can just type in some code-formatted stuff, and hit the `{ }` button in the editor, which should do the same.

Comment: You are welcome. :) gImageReader is quite convenient.

Comment: So gImageReader is the OCR program you used... I thought you didn't retype by hand :P In the mean time I'll study how to use "Sample Code Block" with embedded <NL>, <LF>, <CR> or whatever to make multiple lines.

Comment: Yes, it's a GUI for Tesseract. I did some retyping but not much. To use the code block, just paste all the code, select it and then press the **{}** button on the toolbar.

Comment: Silly me I was clicking **{}** first and then pasting where it said `Enter code here` :)

Answer (score 1):

CUPS, as I'm sure you've discovered, is a very finicky program to say the least.

It appears as though your printer has been added twice to the CUPS printer registry, which would probably be causing this hangup.

Fortunately, you can remedy this from the GUI:

1. Go into the Printers settings menu from the Settings program on your computer.
2. Unplug the troubled printer.
3. Remove the troubled printer from the settings menu.
4. Close and re-open the settings menu to make sure it's actually gone. If not, remove it again.
5. Plug your printer back in, and the system should auto-detect it. Do not manually add the printer.

Be sure to restart any programs that may need the printer so that they can refresh and get the newer (and correct) printer list.

---

Alternatively, you can remove the printer from the CUPS [control webpage](http://localhost:631)*. From there, navigate to the Printers tab and remove the affected printer and any similar entries.

Also, while you are in this panel, you should take a look at the **Jobs** tab and make sure that there isn't a backflow of print jobs that will execute once the printer is (re-)connected.

After you're sure that everything is ready, plug the printer back in and shoot off a test document. It should print after a few seconds.

<sup>* This link will take you to your local CUPS admin panel, present at `localhost:631`. It is here for your convenience only.</sup>